# ErrorException pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: relation &quot;5432posts&quot; does not exist LINE 2: FROM &quot;5432posts&quot;

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter, ubuntu, nginx, crud

so I've been trying to setup a CRUD with CodeIgniter 4 using Postgresql + Nginx

I currently have the databases files set as.

```
database.default.database = igniter_db
database.default.username = user_igniter
database.default.password = pass123
database.default.DBDriver = Postgre
database.default.DBPrefix = 5432
```

and the app/config/database as

```
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
            'username' => 'user_igniter',
            'password' => 'pass123',
            'database' => 'igniter_db',
            'DBDriver' => 'Postgre',
            'DBPrefix' => '',
            'pConnect' => false,
            'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
            'swapPre'  => '',
            'encrypt'  => false,
            'compress' => false,
            'strictOn' => false,
            'failover' => [],
            'port'     => 5432,
```

[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJGl8.png)

Comment: I changed the "config" database from production to development and now this is what I get.

"Error

Call to a member function getResult() on bool "

SYSTEMPATH/Model.php at line 198
```
198             ->getResult($this->tempReturnType);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have configured :

```
database.default.DBPrefix = 5432
```

So now all your tables are prefixed with 5432. 5432 should be port and DBPrefix can be left empty if you don't want to prefix your tables.

Thanks